# WinForms WebBrowser control detect redirections

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

Is there any way to detect 302 redirects within the web browser control that I don't know of? Maybe some kind of magic with the underlying unmanaged control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible with the normal WebBrowser control. Doing anything with the underlying unmanaged control looks very complex, if that's what you're after you could have a look at 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx though:

> csEXWB is a C# .NET 2.0 control that
>   creates, hosts and sinks the events of
>   the original Webbrowser control (Not
>   .NET or any other wrapper). Advanced
>   customization and total control over
>   the Webbrowser control are achieved
>   via implementation of a number of
>   interfaces, along with the addition of
>   many methods, properties, events and a
>   COM library.

That includes being able to view page headers, which is what you'd need to do to detect the HTTP redirect.

Comment: csEXWB will require a lot of work to update.  It does not compile in VS2010 or later and has several bugs (see the CodeProject comments.). Starting from scratch might be easier.  See my comments in @Derek Wade solution below for a method. For these reasons, I have downvoted this answer and upvoted his.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to detect the redirect within the NavigateError event. The statuscode will be 301 or 302. I set a flag that a redirection is to occur. Then in the navigatecomplete2 event, the URL is the redirection URL.  In that event handler I check my redirection flag, and if true, clear the redirect flag and navigate again to the new URL.  This should work for multiple redirects. This is VB6 code, but should work in theory for any WebBrowser implementation.

```
Dim m_isRedirected as boolean
...    
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NavigateComplete2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    If m_isRedirected Then
        m_isRedirected = False  'clear the flag in case another redirect occurs
        WebBrowser1.Navigate2 URL
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_NavigateError(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, Frame As Variant, StatusCode As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
    If StatusCode = 301 Or StatusCode = 302 Then m_isRedirected = True
End Sub
```

Comment: seems like there is no such event (NavigateError)

Comment: NavigateError was added in IE6. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268221(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For C#, derive a class from WebBrowser that adds the NavigateComplete2 and NavigateError events from the OLE DWebBrowserEvents2 interface.
Here is example code for adding the NavigateError event:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.createsink?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: For me IE11 did not fire NavigateError for redirects :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice workaround...
what you can do is capture/overload the webbrowser.OnNavigating and OnNavigated events.

Normally when navigating both the OnNavigating and OnNavigated events get called.
However whenever a redirect occurs the OnNavigated is called, but NOT the OnNavigating event.

so basically I'm using a counter that is reset in the OnNavigating event to 0.
in the OnNavigating  i'm increasing the counter by 1.

in the OnDocumentCompleted event i will check the counter:
if counter == 1, no redirect occured
if counter> 1, redirects have occured.

so far this trick seems to work for me.

Comment: How do you detect that navigation is complete? In my case there are sometimes two, sometimes three redirects (all with status 301 and 302).

Answer (score -1):

Using the WebBrowser control in WPF, you can look for the Navigating event. That won't give you the status codes, but you can see the URLs that the web browser is redirected to, so should be able to figure out when a redirection happens. I'm not that familiar with WinForms, but it may well work in a similar fashion.

```
private void Browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Uri);
}
```